# Get-PowerBIWorkspace in powershell returns blank elements

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I am attempting to pull the various Workspaces and associated user details from Power BI using the Powershell Power BI Management objects. When I make a call to the Get-PowerBIWorkspace in powershell, the user element (and others) is blank

```
Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

$Groups = Get-PowerBIWorkspace

foreach($group in $Groups)
{
    $group
}

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Exampl output

```
Id                    : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
Name                  : test
IsReadOnly            : False
IsOnDedicatedCapacity : False
CapacityId            : 
Description           : 
Type                  : 
State                 : 
IsOrphaned            : False
Users                 : 
Reports               : 
Dashboards            : 
Datasets              : 
Dataflows             : 
Workbooks             :
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: This would return the first 100 workspaces assigned to your credential. You're sure one or more workspaces were assigned to the respective user? Try `Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Include All` to see if you can see any of your organization's workspaces.

Comment: Yes, I can see all the workspaces assigned to my account no problem, it iterates through them as the Id (guid) and Name change. I can pull out the reports associated to each workspace using the Get-PiwerBIReport. However, the Users element of the Workspace object is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more tinkering and I got the below bit of code to list out the users. Obviously it will need some tidying up.

```
$workspaces = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All | Where {($_.Type -eq "Workspace") -and ($_.State -eq "Active")}

foreach ($workspace in $workspaces)
{
    $user = $workspace.Users
    $user.Identifier
}
```

Comment: This is helpful and I am having the same issue. Did you manage to get more detail on this or any documentation?